# apache httpd libapr linking .a .so

Tags: apache-http-server, c, dependencies, aix, httpd

### Problem

I need to compile and install an `Apache` module on `AIX 6.1`. [This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Installing+the+Crowd+Apache+Connector+on+Other+UNIX-Like+Systems) is the module

**A.** The `Apache` module is available only as source. I manageg to compile the source and the `.so` module was created, but when I start `httpd` server, I get this error :

`Could not load module /../httpd.2.2.x/modules/mod_authnz_crowd.so.\n\tDependent module ../httpd.2.2.x/lib/libapr-1.a(libapr-1.so.0.4.6) could not be loaded.\n\tMember libapr-1.so.0.4.6 is not found in archive`

**My conclusion :** its searching for a `httpd.2.2.x/lib/libapr-1.a` which contains `libapr-1.so.0.4.6`

---

**B.** So I searched for this library `libapr-1.a` in other places on my system; its present and contains the `.so` also

**user@myserver** : `cd /usr/lib`

**user@myserver** : `ls -la libapr-1.a`

`libapr-1.a -> ../../opt/freeware/lib/libapr-1.a`

**user@myserver** : `ar -v -t libapr-1.a`

`rwxr-xr-x     0/0     922171 Jul 24 22:05 2012 libapr-1.so.0.4.6`

---

### Question

Is it a linking, LIB, LIBPATH etc. problem ? How do I fix it.

---

**More Info**

- If I create a link `httpd.2.2.x/lib/libapr-1.a -> ../../opt/freeware/lib/libapr-1.a` , it gives a core dump.
- Since this project depends on a lot of other libs, setting `LIB=opt/freeware/lib` makes it fail for other dependencies
- During `make install` is when it tries to restart `apache` and I get the above error. To test, I removed the references to this module from the `httpd.conf` and the server was running again.
- I tried to compile a different version of `apache` from source earlier which was not completely successful. I have also installed an `apr rpm` which was required as a dependency somewhere. So is this because there is a mix up of versions of `apr, apr-util and apache` ?

Comment: Your question is tagged with "unix" but you installed an apr RPM file... which is your OS?

Comment: @jaume  sorry.. shd have mentioned. Update the question'

Comment: The linking should have worked, but a core dump suggests you are facing a tricky problem. I had a look at the Atlassian documentation in  https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Installing+the+Crowd+Apache+Connector+on+Other+UNIX-Like+Systems and other people have struggled to get the connector working in any Linux/Unix distro other than RedHat. You say you don't have `root` privileges and you state in the linked SO question: `I am not *nix expert, rather at basic user level. And any installations are actually done by the admins. ` Can't you ask the admins for advise/help?

Comment: @jaume thanks.. unfortunately the admins are no able to help anymore.. hence I landed here :). Open to experiment.. like copying all required libs into a new directory.. and pointing to that (don't know how to do the pointing part).. or something else.. I don't know

Comment: I was going to try to rephrase your title to a question, but once I got into the body of it, I have no idea what you're asking, so I don't think I'm fit to paraphrase it for you.

Comment: @killermist I have tried to rephrase it myself. Please see if it makes any sense now.